# Locate item below another item that was animated using jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, append

I want to locate a div below a button that changes his position after the user clicked on it.

I implemented an animation to the button and when it finished there is a callback to function that "append" the new div. The new div is ignoring the new position of the button and is positioned at the top of the container.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="inner_body" style="position:relative;margin: auto;text-align: center;width:50%;margin-top: 200px">
        <button class="bc" id="0" style="margin-top: 400px;margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;padding: 20px;background-color: #718bf3">Botton A</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.bc', function () {
         var x = $('#0').position().left;
         var y = $('#0').position().top;
         $('#0').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': y + 'px', 'left': x + 'px' })

         $('#' + this.id + '').animate({ left: 0, marginTop: 0 }, "slow", function () {
              appendnow();
         });

     });

     function appendnow() {
         $('#inner_body').append('<div >Should be below button</div>');
     }
});
```

Comment: i think **ID** should not start with number

Comment: I changed it to letter but still the same behaviour